# relative div resizes to absolute positioned div height depending on content

Tags: jquery, css

I have an absolute positioned div inside a relative positioned div.

I need the parent relative div to re-size to what ever size the absolute div is (this is dynamic changes depending on which page it's on)

I have read that this can be done using jquery but I can't get it to work.

Here is what I have...

Html

```
 <div class="product-view">
<div style="float:left;">Product Image</div>
 <div class="product-shop">
<div id="mm_grid_wrapper">
<table>dynamic content</table>
</div>
```

CSS...

```
    .product-view {
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    padding: 22px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    bottom:0px;


}
.product-view .product-shop {
    text-align: left;
    width: 48%;
    float: left;/*max-width: 329px;*/
}

    #mm_grid_wrapper{
position:absolute;
left:10px;
margin:0 310px 0 0;
max-width: 1630px;
top:0;
height:100%;
}


}
```

javascript...

```
$(function()
{
    $('.product-view') .css({'height': (($('#mm_grid_wrapper').height()) + 20)+'px'});

    $('#mm_grid_wrapper').bind('resize', function(){
        $('.product-view') .css({'height': (($('#mm_grid_wrapper').height()) +20)+'px'});
             });
});
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to make the mm_grid_wrapper relative? This way the parent will automatically resize based on its size.

Comment: @sroes actually my HTML is slightly wrong.. I have amended. no it has to be absoulte otherwise it shrinks to the size of the wrapping div.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the "bottom:0px;" from the product-view class in your css, it will mess up your html.
2. Try to put your jquerycode in the DOM ready listener:

   ```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.product-view') .css({'height': (($('#mm_grid_wrapper').height()) + 20)+'px'});

       $('#mm_grid_wrapper').bind('resize', function(){
         $('.product-view') .css({'height': (($('#mm_grid_wrapper').height()) +20)+'px'});
        });
    });
   ```
3. use the "resize()" and the "height()" function in jquery, so your final code will be like this:

   ```
        $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.product-view').height($('#mm_grid_wrapper').height() + 20);

       $('#mm_grid_wrapper').resize(function(){
         $('.product-view').height($('#mm_grid_wrapper').height() + 20);
        });
    });
   ```